# Is there any specific word to refer to a set of school subjects?

Tags: single-word-requests

In Mexico we use word "bloqe" to refer a set of subjects to give titles to teachers. We need electronic signatures and business cards for them and we're not sure what word to use.
As the Direction is very conservative, decided not to use "set of subjects" and prefer to use only one word which refers to that.

Comment: Your request is a little unclear.  Look up "curriculum" and see if that's the term you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. That word would work on English spoken countries, but in Mexico Curriculum is used to refer to somebody resume (when asking for a job), so I don't think it works. What I need to know if there is any single word which means Subject Set, only one word which express the same idea of Subject Set. Talking about school subjects.

Comment: Google `curriculum synonym` (in an English language version of Google).

Comment: Yes, I just did and found that "Module" can be the best choice. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: _Module_ does not seem the right term. In education a _module_ usually refers to a unit of study within a subject, not _a set of subjects_. Are you trying to distinguish teachers from other members of the organisation? Or are you trying to distinguish teachers by the subject or set of subjects they teach? If the latter, why not just refer to the subject group: Arts, Humanities, Sciences, Languages, etc?

Comment: ***College*** of Arts and Sciences, ***Faculty*** of Engineering, ***Department*** of Physics, ***School*** of ...  These are all examples found on professors' business cards I found online.

Comment: module are subjects placed together but not necessarily organically related to each other...Sorry, but you mean: bloque, right? And we don't say direction here, we say: administration.

Answer (score 1):

What about 'discipline'?

As in, 'The different disciplines.'

According to [Merriam Webster's definition 4](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discipline):

> a field of study

Answer (score 0):

In the UK I think we'd use "Department"

The Science Department teaches physics, chemistry, and biology; the Modern Languages Department teaches French, German, and Spanish.

But "department" refers to part of the school management, not to the group of subjects itself. We say modern languages, sciences, humanities, etc for specific groups.

Answer (score 0):

Having been encouraged to read the question again, I read through it a couple more times and I may, indeed, have misunderstood. If you are looking for a word to describe the set of subjects *that a particular teacher* is responsible for, then I would suggest **specialism**:

> specialization in an occupation or branch of learning

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/specialism)

---

Curriculum:

> The subjects comprising a course of study in a school or college

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/curriculum)

British English also uses curriculum (in *curriculum vitae* or CV) to refer to a resume. Context usually resolves any ambiguity.

Syllabus is close (but not as good as curriculum):

> The subjects in a course of study or teaching.

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/syllabus)

I think of syllabus as narrower in scope than curriculum. Syllabus is the set of subjects for a specific course, whereas curriculum is all the courses available.

Comment: @AleksandrH Yes, it asked for a "specific word to refer to a set of school subjects". The obvious words, to me, are curriculum or syllabus. As you obviously have a better answer, why not post it.

Comment: a set of school subjects is most definitely a curriculum. I really get miffed about the only answer that works getting downvoted.

Comment: @Lambie -  Not my down vote, but I interpret the question differently.  OP mentions this would be used for a title. I conclude (because it's certainly not clear) that the set of subjects is more along the lines of "Arts and Humanities", "Physics" etc.  So in my opinion, words like "Department, College, Faculty, etc or more in line with what OP is looking for.  Just my interpretation though. OP needs to clarify and give examples.